# How do I assert an element contains the specified text in FluentAutomation?

Tags: contains, assert, fluentautomation

Is it possible to check that a text is contained in the text of an element using the FluentAutomation framework ?

The example provided in the documentation is for matching exact text 
http://fluent.stirno.com/docs/#asserts-text

```
I.Assert.Text("FluentAutomation").In("header");
```

How do I check the element contains the text ?

Ex: 
      header text is "Random text I don't need Mytext and etc."

I want to assert that header contains "MyText" using FluentAutomation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used  `Assert.True` http://fluent.stirno.com/docs/#asserts-true
and evaluated if I find the element that contains the wanted string :

```
I.Assert.True(() => I.Find(MyElement).Text().Contains("teststring"));
```